# How can I remove current user in the foreach php in this situation?

Tags: php, mysql

My foreach will echo out all users that match. But I don't want to show the user himself, so I want to remove the current user in the foreach loop, but I have no idea what I should do. Look at my code, I want to do if $member_id=$current_user, then don't show this one, echo out others. What is the best way to do this? Appreciate.

```html
<?php
$current_user=$_POST['users_id'];
//my mysql connection code here. There is no need for this question.

foreach ($rows as $query_row) {
 $member_id=$query_row['user_id'];
    //if $member_id=$current_user, then don't show this one
 echo "<div>$member_id</div>"; 
     
}


?>
```

Comment: Remove from where? i.e. from the array `$rows` or from the db?

Comment: from the array $row,  the foreach will echo out all users that match, but I don't want to show the current user himself, so I want to make it disappear.

Comment: If you just want to suppress that printout rather than actually remove from the array (i.e. you're not using the array again later) then you can just make your commented out if-statement a real one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
If ($member_id == $current_user) continue;
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That works! However, I don't know the logic of that code. if $member_id equal the $current_user, why continue will unset the current user?

Comment: You're welcome,  "continue" says to the "for  each loop" to skip the current element and to continue to iterate